# Difference between cfparam and cfargument in a coldfusion function?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cffunction

What's the difference between these two blocks of code, when called right after a cffunction tag:

```
<cfparam name="bork_bork_bork" default="false">

<cfargument name="bork_bork_bork" required="false" default="false">
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<cfparam>`, when used with the default attribute, will ensure that a variable exists. Because there is no scope specified, `bork_bork_bork` is being put in to the `Variables` scope.

`<cfargument>` is used to pass an arguments to a function. These values are stored in the `Arguments` scope. You would access the value using `arguments.bork_bork_bork`.

Note that `arguments.bork_bork_bork` and `bork_bork_bork` are not the same. The scope of `arguments` is only within the function, the other is being stored in the `Variables` scope and will be valid anywhere on the page (though I would not recommend coding it that way.)

Comment: +1 for this important clarification. Furthermore, if the cffunction resides in a CFC and that CFC is cached in a persistent memory scope (ie. APPLICATION), then a cfparam'd variable will persist for the life of that object (because of this same VARIABLES scope explanation), including multiple requests, and potentially multiple calls per request...which, if you don't specifically plan for that logic...can be quite difficult to catch/debug.

Comment: +1. Also keep in mind cfparam interacts with a whole [list of scopes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fdf.html). If `bork_bork_bork` is already declared in *any* of those scopes, the default will not be applied, again leading to unexpected results. In this context, better to use cfargument.

Answer (score 2):

cfparam has nothing to do with functions. I can see that this is confusing, given that param/argument are interchangeable words in most languages. Keep in mind that user-defined functions weren't added to CF until version 5, so there was no conflict in using cfparam as a way to initialize variables. Moreover, the cfparam tag probably drew its name from the now obsolete function, ParameterExists() (or vice versa - by the time I got into CF, at version 4.0 (1999), that function was already deprecated, so I missed the history behind it)

Answer (score 1):

cfparam is a way to set a default for any variable if the variable doesn't already exist.  It's a shortcut to do the following:

```
<cfif NOT isDefined('bork_bork_bork')>
    <cfset bork_bork_bork = 'myDefaultSetting'>
</cfif>
```

cfargument is only useable after a  opening tag to define an argument being passed to a CFC function or a user-defined function.

From what I recall, nothing can exist between the cffunction tag and cfargument tag, so they must appear right after the cffunction tag.

Answer (score 0):

From within the function you'll access cfargument via the arguments scope {arguments.bork_bork_bork} or via an array {arguments[1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e47.html)}

cfparam will just ensure the variable is available on the request is should not be used instead of cfargument. For further reading check out:

[cfargument](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e47.html)

[Using the Arguments scope as an array](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/UDFs_08.html#1194005)

[Defining functions by using the cffunction tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=UDFs_05.html)